# Conda skeleton from pyproject.toml

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to build my first conda package but I am running in troubles.
My package is available on `pypi` and I am trying to follow the [conda commands](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-skeleton-pypi.html) by issuing `conda skeleton --recursive mypackage`.

Nevertheless, it seems that in order to create recipes from `pypi` it is required the `pypi` packages to have a `setup.py`, which is not my case as I use the new `pyproject.toml` way.

I am wondering if there is a method to create a `conda skeleton` directly from `pyproject.toml` given that a lot of needed information is already contained in there. Should I wait for `Anaconda` team to update their building system?

In the meantime I have noticed [grayskull](https://github.com/conda-incubator/grayskull) package but I would avoid to have yet another dependency.

Comment: I have the same problem. The only thing I could find is this https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10633. The ticket was closed without any further notice. I don't like conda..

Comment: Good to know. The issue looks open btw, but it’s  there from 2021 and it addresses the creation of new environments from pyproject.toml files. Other than that I agree that they should support pyproject.toml pretty much for everything.